# Overwrite Django "Using" method

Tags: django, postgresql, django-managers

I want to use PostgreSQL multi schema in Django.

I want to overwrite **using** method to make my query according schema name.

I want like this:

```
objs=MyModel.objects.using('schema_name')
objs.filter(...) # extra codes
```

Comment: See the postgres docs on schema usage patterns: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-schemas.html 
I would suggest creating a database user per schema as mentioned there and set up your DATABASES settings to have a database per user/schema, so each "database" is really just a connection to a particular schema.